# Cascading (Dependent) DropDownList using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dropdown

I have implemented Cascading (Dependent) DropDownList using ASP.NET MVC.

This is the [tutorial](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Cascading-Dependent-DropDownList-without-using-Entity-Framework-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx)

Now I need show alert message box after insert data and redirect on Index page in ASP.NET MVC.

To show alert message in ASP.NET MVC after insert data using store procedure from MySQL database, I have write the code like as shown below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
       var msg = '@ViewData["result"]';
          if (msg > 0)
          {
             alert("User Details Inserted Successfully");
             window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Index", "Home")";
          }
});
</script>
```

The data is correctly registered in the database table and the alert message box after insert data it's show.

But the redirect to `index.cshtml` not working because all the DropDownList on the form are empty except the first DropDownList that populates correctly.

```
window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Index", "Home")";
```

I mean that all other (populated cascading) DropDownList are enabled but empty.

I need redirect to Index Action page and being able to reload a new record, with this redirection it is impossible because the populated cascading DropDownList remain empty... instead of disabled and populated from value of first dropdownlist...

How to do resolve this?

Thanks.

**Update 2021-01-02**

```
@section Scripts {

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/DatePicker.js");
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/cssjqryUi")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var msg = '@ViewData["result"]';
            console.log(msg);
              if (msg > 0)
              {
                  alert("User Details Inserted Successfully");
                  var url = "@Url.Action("Index", "Home")";
                  window.location.href = url;
              }
    });
    </script>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function ($) {
            $.validator.addMethod('date',
                function (value, element) {
                    if (this.optional(element)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    var ok = true;
                    try {
                        $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', value);
                    }
                    catch (err) {
                        ok = false;
                    }
                    return ok;
                });

        $("#thedate").datepicker(options);

        $(function () {
            $(".loading").hide();
            $("select").each(function () {
                if ($(this).find("option").length <= 1) {
                    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            });

            $("select").change(function () {
                var value = 0;
                if ($(this).val() != "") {
                    value = $(this).val();
                }
                var id = $(this).attr("id");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Home/AjaxMethod",
                    data: '{type: "' + id + '", value: "' + value + '"}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        var dropDownId;
                        var list;
                        switch (id) {

                            case "CountryId":
                                list = response.States;

                                DisableDropDown("#TicketId");
                                DisableDropDown("#CityId");

                                dropDownId = "#TicketId";
                                list = response.Ticket;
                                PopulateDropDown("#TicketId", list);

                                break;

                            case "TicketId":
                                list = response.States;
                                DisableDropDown("#StateId");
                                PopulateDropDown("#StateId", list);

                                break;

                            case "StateId":
                                dropDownId = "#CityId";
                                list = response.Cities;
                                DisableDropDown("#CityId");
                                PopulateDropDown("#CityId", list);

                                dropDownId = "#CityId2";
                                list = response.Cities2;
                                PopulateDropDown("#CityId2", list);

                                $("#GPS").val(response.GPS);

                                break;
                        }

                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
        });

        function DisableDropDown(dropDownId) {
            $(dropDownId).attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $(dropDownId).empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="">[ === Select === ]</option>');
        }

        function PopulateDropDown(dropDownId, list) {
            var modal = $('<div />');
            modal.addClass("modalBackground");
            $('body').append(modal);
            var loading = $(".loading");
            loading.show();
            var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
            var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
            loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
            setTimeout(function () {
                if (list != null && list.length > 0) {
                    $(dropDownId).removeAttr("disabled");
                    $.each(list, function () {
                        $(dropDownId).append($("<option></option>").val(this['Value']).html(this['Text']));
                    });
                    $(".loading").hide();
                    $('.modalBackground').remove();
                }
            }, 1000);
        }

    </script>
}
```

**update controller**

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(PersonModel person)
{                
    MTsqlinsert(person); //Insert values in the database

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        PersonModel personModel = new PersonModel();

        person.Countries = PopulateDropDown("SELECT CountryId, CountryName FROM Countries", "CountryName", "CountryId");
        person.States = PopulateDropDown("SELECT StateId, StateName FROM States WHERE CountryId = " + countryId, "StateName", "StateId");
        person.Cities = PopulateDropDown("SELECT CityId, CityName FROM Cities WHERE StateId = " + stateId, "CityName", "CityID");

        ViewData["result"] = "1";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(person);
}

[HttpGet]
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 60, VaryByParam = "*")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    PersonModel personModel = new PersonModel
    {
       Countries = PopulateDropDown("SELECT CountryId, CountryName FROM Countries", "CountryName", "CountryId");
    };

    return View(personModel);
}
```

Comment: If you put the script by the bottom of Index body (before closing body) and set result to 1 in post action method, it does what you claim it doesn't. So I guess you're doing something different or the rest of the code is not the same you got from tutorial.

Comment: See https://ibb.co/nPLBKg0

Comment: @DanielManta Thank you for reply. Please see **Update 2021-01-02** in my first question. If I put the script by the bottom of Index body (before closing body) and set result to 1 in post action method, don't have confirm msg...

Comment: All right, so the code is not the same as published in this tutorial. Anyway you don't need to use javascript for redirecting to index. You just want to reset the model and this can be done in the controller.

Comment: @DanielManta What mean reset the model in the controller?